# Django - Inline formset always has error on POST

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a inline formset:

```
OptionFormset = inlineformset_factory(App, AppOptions, can_delete=True, extra=1,
            fields = ['options', 'conditions'])
```

When submitting the forms I do a verification in the template:

```
      {% if formset.errors %}
          <p style="color: red;">
              Please correct the error:
          {{ formset.errors }}
          </p>
      {% endif %}
```

The print returns that:

```
Please correct the error [{}, {}]
```

Obviously, there is no error in the form, and their is no error in formset.errors The error is probably in the view?

view.py:

```
  def setAppOption(request, app_name):
      app_selected = App.objects.get(app_name=app_name, created_by=request.user)
      formset = OptionsFormSet(instance=fusionTable_selected)
      if request.method == 'POST':
          formset = OptionFormset(request.POST, instance=fusionTable_selected)
            if formset.is_valid():   
              formset.save()

      return render_to_response("ezApp/manage__Options.html", {'formset': formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py

```
    class App(models.Model):
        layer_name = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.layer_name

    class AppOptions(models.Model):
        app = models.ForeignKey(EzApp)
        condition = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
        option = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying formset.errors correctly

```
{% for dict in formset.errors %}
    {% for error in dict.values %}           
        Please correct the error: {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did that, but curiously {& if formset.errors %} is true but there is no error displayed. Its just written Please correct the error:

Comment: Its curious that I can save the form even with the error message. In the view I use formset.is_valid() and it saves.

Comment: Sorry, I will search for that why if formset.errors return to True